# Monitor CPU usage over period of time on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, central-processing-unit, top

Is there some way to monitor my CPU usage over a period of time, e.g. get a graph that shows CPU% vs. date/time? I occasionally see high load using htop, but I'd like to see what's happening throughout the day.

The more lightweight, the better :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php) for Linux which is in Ubuntu build.  You can run `nmon` in 'spreadsheet' mode where it samples data every few minutes and saves it to a file.  There are various tools for then graphing that, or you can just review the data manually.

More complex options include things like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), etc. but they look at just more than straight CPU.

Comment: Checkout https://sealion.com. Another free tool doing the same. Easy to setup and has a convenient interface to view the output.

Comment: It is worth mention that in case you use the GUI, use the `c` option to view current CPU usage,or the  `l` option to view the CPU usage over time (along a time "axis").

Answer (score 2):

The command `sar` is intended to do this and should be available by default under Ubuntu as the `sysstat` package.

It's output is plain-text rather than graphical, but `kSar` is intended to take this data and make it pretty for you.  This may need to be built or found in an unsupported repository.  (I don't know.)

[nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/identifying-linux-bottlenecks-sar-graphs-with-ksar.html) did a great write up on the tool you may want to refer to for more information.